# what is the difference between an anti-join and an anti semi join?

Tags: sql, database, join

From http://www.dbspecialists.com/files/presentations/semijoins.html

> An “anti-join” between two tables returns rows from the first table
>   where no matches are found in the second table. An anti-join is
>   essentially the opposite of a semi-join: While a semi-join returns one
>   copy of each row in the first table for which at least one match is
>   found, **an anti-join returns one copy of each row in the first table
>   for which no match is found**.

Isn't an anti semi-join instead of an anti-join the one which "returns one copy of each row in the first table for which no match is found"?

If it is, what is the definition of an anti-join?

Note that my question is at the general level of SQL, such as at the level of college text books on database concepts, not specific to a particular SQL RDBMS implementation

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anti-semijoin is anti join.

> The antijoin can also be defined as the complement of the semijoin, as follows:
>
> R ▷ S = R − R ⋉ S
>
> Given this, the antijoin is sometimes called the anti-semijoin, and the antijoin operator is sometimes written as semijoin symbol with a bar above it, instead of ▷.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29